# why len(measure.regionprops(imgl)) gives me a wrong number of objects?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I used this function to count objects in segmendted images (I loaded my pretrained weights for prediction)

```
import pandas as pd
import skimage.io
import skimage.segmentation

def process_images(img):
 img1=img
 test_img1 = np.expand_dims(img1, axis=0)
 prediction = model.predict(test_img1)
 prediction_img=np.argmax(prediction, axis=3)[0,:,:]
 pred=prediction_img
 for i in range(0,512):
    for j in range(0,512):
        if pred[i,j]==1:
           pred[i,j]=0
        elif pred[i,j]==2:
           pred[i,j]=255  

 imgwater=np.stack((pred,)*3, axis=-1)


 kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
 predd=np.uint8(pred)
 predd=skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects(predd, min_size=25) 
 predd=skimage.morphology.remove_small_holes(predd,area_threshold=50)
 annot = skimage.morphology.label(predd,connectivity=2)
 annot=color.label2rgb(annot,bg_label=0)
 imgl=measure.label(predd, background=0,connectivity=2)
 propsa = measure.regionprops(imgl)
 a = len(propsa)
 return img, prediction_img,annot,pred,a

k=4 
imgo=image_dataset[k]
test_img = X[k]

img,prediction_img,annot,pred,a=process_images(test_img)
print(a)

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8),dpi=90)
plt.subplot(231)
plt.title('Orginal Image')
plt.imshow(imgo,cmap='gray')
plt.subplot(232)
plt.title('Predicted image')
plt.imshow(prediction_img,cmap='jet')
plt.subplot(233)
plt.title('Predicted thresholded')
plt.imshow(pred,cmap='gray')
plt.subplot(234)
plt.title('result')
plt.show()
```

I tried this function with my first dataset and it counts correctly the cells in the images. but when I tried other images, len(measure.regionprops(imgl)) gives me a totally wrong count (it adds sometimes 8)
here is an example, len(propsa) gives me 130 while when I count the cells in the result image i found 125.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leEE2.png)
I really don't understand where is the problem, the function never gave me a wrong count in the result image with the first dataset (the returned value is always equal to the manually counted cells in the result image) but the images in the second dataset always adds 1 or 2 or even 8 And I am not talking about the prediction, I am only talking about the result image. Even if there are noisy pixels in the images I believe that I got rid of them with:

```
predd=skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects(predd, min_size=25)
```

Please help me, I am about to pull my hair out. If you want any additional information please don't hesitate to comment. Thank you in advance

Comment: This is not answerable, as `measure` is not self-contained in your code. Please create a copy-pastable example. Read [mre]

Comment: @Gulzar I know this is not reproducible, if you should try the code I should provide all the notebook, the weights.h5, the dataset which I can't do because of my compant restrictions. All I can say is that my model predict background(0), cells edges(1) and cells (2) then I gave the cells the pixel value of 255 and the background and edges 0. after that I used skimage to label the objects and count them and as I told you the count was correct with images from the first dataset but with the second it adds a number of cells which don't figure in the result image which is odd.

Comment: I am asking for help and knowledge about computer vision and skimage thanks in advance.

Comment: You should ask an answerable question which an outsider can answer. Be focused. Can't help you otherwise.

Comment: @Gulzar, I understand, thank you anyway.

Comment: I can't see the reason from a quick read. When you say "when I count the cells", what does this mean? You should have one regionprops for each non-zero label in imgl. So, return imgl, and check the output of `np.unique(imgl)` and make sure it matches what you expect. You might be surprised.

Comment: @Juan I meant that when I counted the cells manually and carefully in the labled image (the colored one the result ) I find 125 but the len(measure.regionprops(imgl)) and np.unique(imgl) says 130. do you understand me ?

Comment: I found out the problem, I believe there were some tiny pixels considered and counted as cells, skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects(predd, min_size=25) didn't do it job because it expects predd to be an array with labeled objects, so putting this line under annot = skimage.morphology.label(predd,connectivity=2) solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove_small_objects expected a labeled image, putting:
imgl=skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects(imgl, min_size=12)
under
imgl=measure.label(predd, background=0,connectivity=2)
solved the problem.

```
def process_images(img):
 img1=img
 test_img1 = np.expand_dims(img1, axis=0)
 prediction = model.predict(test_img1)
 prediction_img=np.argmax(prediction, axis=3)[0,:,:]
 #print(np.unique(prediction_img))
 #prediction = (model.predict(test_img1)[0]> 0.5).astype(np.uint8)
 pred=prediction_img
 for i in range(0,512):
   for j in range(0,512):
    if pred[i,j]==1:
     pred[i,j]=0
    elif pred[i,j]==2:
     pred[i,j]=255  

 imgwater=np.stack((pred,)*3, axis=-1)


 kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
 #no need for morphology because il will eliminate the tiny cells
 predd=np.uint8(pred)
 predd=skimage.morphology.remove_small_holes(predd,area_threshold=100)
 imgl=measure.label(predd, background=0,connectivity=2)
 imgl=skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects(imgl, min_size=12) 
 annot2=color.label2rgb(imgl,bg_label=0)

 propsa = measure.regionprops(imgl)
 #print(propsa)
 a = len(propsa)
 return img, prediction_img,annot2,pred,a
```